# How to pass value to headerRight button

Tags: react-navigation

When use the `react-navigation` and add the headerRight button

```
...
class Screen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    headerRight: (
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Icon .../>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View />
    )
  }
}
```

Then I want to animate this button, but I encounter a problem when passing value

```
...
class Screen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    headerRight: (
      <Animated.View style={animatedStyle}>      <---- how to pass it 
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Icon .../>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Animated.View>
    )
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(0)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Animated.timing(...}).start()
  }

  render() {
    const interpolateRotation = ...
    const animatedStyle = ...                    <---- the animatedStyle value
    return (
      <View />
    )
  }
}
```

I have tried the `this.animatedStyle` and `animatedStyle` for `Animated.View`, but it also can not effectiveness. It seems `static navigationOptions` is not inline within the `class Screen`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this.props.navigation.setParams({ headerRightButtonStyle: this.animatedValue })` in constructor or `componentWillMount` to pass this value. Then read it like this:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  const params = navigation.state.params
  return {
    headerRight: (
      <Animated.View style={params.headerRightButtonStyle}>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Icon .../>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Animated.View>
    )
  }
}
```

`setParams` will also trigger header rerender. You can use this method to pass header title/style/etc.

Related documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers.html#using-params-in-the-title

Comment: Thank a lot, but `this.animatedValue` can not be referenced to the specific const variable in the render method